# Error "Cannot read property 'style' of null" in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

As a javascript beginner I want to create an extension to display a modal when a user points a URL in Google Chrome. In an HTML where I have put HTML + CSS + JS in one file, it works fine but putting it into a Chrome extension gets me this error message:"Cannot read property 'style' of null" for line `"modal.style.display = "block";"` in content_script.js. It seems that modal is null and the modal does not show up. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

content_script.js with JS:

```
var modal  = document.createElement ('iframe');
modal.src  = chrome.extension.getURL ('./options.html');
document.body.appendChild (modal);

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  var srcElement = e.srcElement;
  if (srcElement.nodeName == 'A') {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
  if (srcElement.nodeName != 'A') {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    } 
}, false);
```

options.html - the content of the modal in HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

manifest.json

```
{
   "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": ["background.js" ]
   },

   "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon128.png"
   },

   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": ["content_script.js"],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "css" : ["css.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],

   "description": "Description",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.png",
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png"
   },

   "web_accessible_resources": [
    "options.html"]
   ,

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Name",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Your `modal` doesn't have an id so `var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");` won't find anything. Simply remove this line to use the already assigned value.

Comment: If you insert your HTML in  a `iframe` you cannot access its components through `document`.

Comment: @wOxxOm it has `<div id="myModal" class="modal">`, but it is loaded into an `iframe` not the `document`. I'd also recommend not reusing the variable `modal`, for clarity.

Comment: Is there an alternative to load the html file into the document instead of iframe?

Answer (score 1):

An `<iframe>` is a separate document. Its content is not directly accessible from the document in which the `<iframe>` exists. In fact, access between such documents may be restricted for security reasons, which is one of the reasons to use iframes.

Your code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
```

is attempting to access the content of the `<iframe>` by searching in the top level `document`. The iframe's content does not exist in the top level document, so the element with the ID `myModal` is not found. Thus, `modal` is now `null`, which causes your error. You need to perform your search for the ID within the `<iframe>` document, which is accessed with [`.contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument):

```
var myModalDiv = modal.contentDocument.getElementById("myModal");
```

NOTE: Part of the confusion is using the same variable name to both reference your `<iframe>` and to try to reference the top `<div>` within the `<iframe>`. You should not reuse variable names in this way, as it generates confusion as to what your variable represents. Under most circumstances, a variable should be named to match what it represents. Usually, there is no reason to reuse variable names in this manner. If you are going to do so and the variable is going to represent multiple things, then that should be indicated in the variable's name.

Comment: Thanks. I still get the same error: "Cannot read property 'style' of null". I've solved it by creating the div in the javascript with instead of referring to the external html file: `var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "myModal";`